# Upload Image Using AFnetwork 3 Multipart getting nil parameters

Tags: objective-c, parameters, image-uploading, afnetworking-3

Currently, i am working on a project. I am uploading an image with parameters using afnetwork. It's working fine on wifi  but if I use cellular network. it's not passing parameters correctly. Like few times back end server receiving parameters. Sometimes missing.  The code i am using is

```
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASEURL,urlID]; // some URL
NSLog(@"URL : %@ Parameters %@",URLString,postVars);

AFHTTPSessionManager *uploadManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[uploadManager POST:URLString parameters:postVars constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    NSLog(@"Parameters %@",postVars);

    if (profileImageData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:profileImageData name:@"photo" fileName:@"myimage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
    if ([[responseObject valueForKey:@"status"]isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
        block(responseObject,nil);
    }
    else{

        block(responseObject,nil);
    }


} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    if([[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"] isEqualToString:AFNETWORK_OFFLINE_MESSAGE])
    {
        [alertHelper showAlertwithTitle:NOINTERNET_TITLE details:NOINTERNET_DETAILS];
    }
    block(nil,error);
}];
```

Uploading image with parameters working on wifi but on cellular network sometimes paramenters missing on AFNetwork. My Backend Developer informed me that you are not sending parameters on the time of uploading image. What should i do right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if your parameter is nil then paas nil instead of _params.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *_params=[[ NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[_params setObject:postsomthingtext.text forKey:@"body"];
[_params setObject:userid forKey:@"user_id"];


NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(choosedimg,.6);
documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
// Here is the file path for the image
filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imagename.png"]];
[imageData writeToFile:filepath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager*operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
operationManager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [operationManager POST:@"http://ekisansansar.com/application/webservices/Webservicefiles.php" parameters: _params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSError *error;
    if (![formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath] name:@"upload_file" fileName:[filepath lastPathComponent] mimeType:@"image/png" error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error appending part: %@", error);
    }
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseObject = %@", result);




} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];

if (!operation) {
    NSLog(@"Creation of operation failed.");
}
```

Comment: I am always sending parameter's on wifi it's perfectly reaching to the server. But when using Mobile data I am also requesting with parameters and on the server side, i am getting empty parameters. Here The parameters I am sending not reaching to the server for 3g data. Did u get my point?

Comment: Try after increse time session of request or Check after debugging in your backend side ,why your parameter is not going to server with mobile data